# Mysql - What is the fastest way to retrieve records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

example: i create table post -

```
post_id primary key

content varchar
```

and then i create table comment -

```
comment_id primary key

post_id foreign key reference post(post_id)

content varchar
```

show records in ASP(Active Server Pages)

```
query1: select * from post;

Do while NOT RS1.EOF
{
response.write RS1("post_id")
response.write RS1("content")

query2: select * from comment where post_id = RS1("post_id")

Do while NOT RS2.EOF
{
    response.write RS2("comment_id")
    response.write RS2("content")
}
}
```

the second query perform a fullscan in table comment for each record in table post, is there any way to make comment search faster than the above method?
do i need to use index for that case? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    post a
        INNER JOIN comment b
            ON a.Post_ID = b.Post_ID
-- WHERE   a.Post_ID = @valueHere       -- <<== if you want to get specific post
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply
JW: Ok i'll use JOIN
@Randy: which post_id? in post table or comment?

Comment: you don;t need to define an index manually because from your table definition, you have already set it as primary key and on table `comment` it is already a foreign key.

Comment: @JW ok, if it is no need to use index, do you have suggestion for better ASP code to get faster result? or i just have to change the query to use JOIN table?

Answer (score 2):

Add an index for 'post_id' to 'comment'.

You could also do a join between these two tables to get all the comments for each post using one query. This might be expensive if you have lots of posts though...